# Why does the Newsletter's "Top new questions" include unanswered ones?

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

I'm a lurker on Skeptics.SE, and several other SE sites. I personally don't really have the expertise or time to answer questions there, but find the content interesting. So I subscribe to the weekly newsletter.

However, often when I get the Skeptics.SE newsletter, and also sometimes the Home Improvement newsletter, I open one of the top questions, only to find out there is no answer. For example, here are a few from the Skeptics.SE newsletter that I just received:

- [Did a group of U.S. women propose to send black kids instead of dogs to
  space?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18473/did-a-group-of-u-s-women-propose-to-send-black-kids-instead-of-dogs-to-space)
- [Does storing powdered coffee in the fridge preserve its flavor
  better?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18490/does-storing-powdered-coffee-in-the-fridge-preserve-its-flavor-better)
- [Is 90% of the large fish biomass gone, when compared to pre-industrial
  levels?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18504/is-90-of-the-large-fish-biomass-gone-when-compared-to-pre-industrial-levels)

Those are also the first three things in the Newsletter. These are in the "top questions" section, not the "can you answer these?" section.

I suggest that "top questions" should be limited only to questions with answers. Ones which don't have answers should go in the "can you answer these?" section instead.